# Whats wrong with this code? It is throwing an IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, exception

The following code is throwing an exception:

```
public class Medicine {

 private String  name;
 private Double dose;
 private ArrayList<Time> time = new ArrayList<Time>();
 private Unit unit;
 private int index = 0;

 public Time getNextTime() {
    return time.get(index++);//it throws it in this line. It says Caused by:  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
 }
```

UPDATE 1:
okay okay, I'm adding a bit more code. The following calls the exception-throwing-line:

```
(t = medicine.getNextTime())!= null
```

Comment: What results ware you expecting and why?

Comment: @Psherno Well, I truncated code. I'm writing an entire Android App. Its isn't right for me to divulge all the classes and layout files of the project. So, I figured, that I would remove the non-error code and just paste the important bits of the class. Note that the Time is of type enum.

Comment: So based on exception message we can see that your list has two elements, and you are attempting to read element with index `2`. Do you think this should work (remember that indexes starts from `0`)?

Comment: Based on your added code it looks like you are expecting `time.get(index++)` to return `null` if you use incorrect index. Unfortunately that is not true and `ArrayList.get` handles invalid indexes by throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which you clearly see in your logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Invalid index 2, size is 2

That's your problem. If `size` is `2`, the valid indexes are `0` and `1`, but you tried to use `2` for some reason.

You haven't shown your code adding to `time` (although clearly something is, or you would have gotten `Invalid index 0, size is 0`), but clearly something is calling `getNextTime` more often than whatever is adding to `time`.

Since `getNextTime` is a public method, you might want to make it defensive:

```
public Time getNextTime() {
    if (index < time.size()) {
        return time.get(index++);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Blah blah blah");
}
```

(Or `return null` if it's not an exceptional condition for the caller to call the method too often.)

---

Re your update:

> The following calls the exception-throwing-line:
>
> ```
> (t = medicine.getNextTime())!= null
> ```

If you want `null` when you call `getNextTime` too often, then as I said above, you have to *code* that (above I guessed that it was an exceptional condition, not a normal one):

```
public Time getNextTime() {
    if (index >= time.size()) {
        return null;
    }
    return time.get(index++);
}
```

of if you really like one-liners:

```
public Time getNextTime() {
    return index < time.size() ? time.get(index++) : null;
}
```

---

I should also note that if whatever's adding to `time` might be running on a separate thread from whatever's calling `getNextTime`, you'll need to add some synchronization...

Comment: ahem. I already increment the index with the index++ within the return statement.

Comment: @Catfish: ahem. That has nothing to do with the fact that calling `getNextTime` three times when you've only added two entries to `time` will fail because the index is invalid. All incrementing `index` in `getNextTime` does is...increment `index`. It's not like it magically fills in more entries in your `time` list.

Comment: @TJ Crowder Oh! so you mean my code shouldnt be invoking the getNextTime() any more that the number of times there are objects in the Collection (ArrayList)? This impliers, I have to create a second hasNextTime() method, right? Tell me yes and I say your answer as correct!

Comment: @Catfish: I'm saying if you want to allow for that, you have to code for it in `getNextTime`, because calling `.get(index)` on a list will fail with that exception if you ask for an index that's out of range. (The general term for this is "guarding" the call to `.get`.) You don't *have* to create a `hasNextTime`, but that's also a reasonable approach.

Comment: @TJ Crowder Yay! my code is working with your modification.